# Creating a simple function to compute the average of the difference between pairs of elements in an array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the form:

```
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{9, 10}, {11, 12}}}
```

How can I create a function which will take each set at the highest level of the list:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}

{{9, 10}, {11, 12}}
```

And subtract the first element of the set from the second element of the set, here:

```
{3, 4} - {1, 2} = {2, 2}

{7, 8} - {5, 6} = {2, 2}

{11, 12} - {9, 10} = {2, 2}
```

Then compute the average or median of these values (`{2, 2}` here in either case)?  It's clear how to do this using loops or tables, but is there a simpler way to proceed that makes clever use of *Mathematica*?

For a table based implementation:

```
PairList = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{9, 10}, {11, 12}}};
PLMean = Mean[Table[PairList[[u, 2]] - PairList[[u, 1]], {u, 1, Length[PairList]}]]
```

Comment: using your last table "form" example better just to use `Part` with the entire list: `Mean[list[[All, 2]] - list[[All, 1]]]`

Answer (score 17):

What about this?:

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{9, 10}, {11, 12}}}
Mean[Subtract @@@ Reverse /@ list]
```

A shorter one:

```
Mean[Plus[-#, #2] & @@@ list]
```

A even shorter one:

```
Mean[#2 - #1 & @@@ list]
```

Comment: You calculate the `Mean` of a pair ("intra") individually, I think he wants the `Mean` of all pairs ("inter"). Maybe I am mistaken though..

Comment: @PinguinDirk Oh…Sorry for my poor English, fixed.

Comment: I wouldn't blame your english (I got it wrong too), but the code he added made it clear :)

Comment: @xzczd Terrific, this is really nice looking.

Comment: @xzczd How can I understand @@@?

Comment: @user8646 You can check the document of [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)

Comment: @user8646 Please also see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121).

Comment: You can also use `Differences` instead of `Subtract @@@ Reverse` in this case (gives an extra `{}` though).

Answer (score 10):

Also this:

```
{-1, 1}.Mean@list
```

or this (looks nicer in the front end):

```
Mean[{-1, 1}.list\[Transpose]]
```

It is worth noting that the first form is considerably more time efficient than the second, though both are fast (warning, several GB RAM used):

```
list = RandomReal[99, {30000000, 2, 2}];

{-1, 1}.Mean@list              // Timing // First

Mean[{-1, 1}.list\[Transpose]] // Timing // First
```

> 0.1902
>
> 0.921

The second also uses about 2.5X as much memory as figured by `MaxMemoryUsed[]`.

Comment: Simon, I hate you. ;-) (I was sniffing around `Dot` trying to solve this puzzle and I failed.  Well done!)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Heh heh. For those who like compact code the standard form of `Dot` must surely rate as one of the best in terms of functionality per pixel. *And* it's infix... :-)

Answer (score 9):

This method should be the most efficient:

```
Mean[#[[All, 2]] - #[[All, 1]]& @ {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{9, 10}, {11, 12}}}]
```

> ```
> {2, 2}
> ```

Another method (of many possible) is more complicated and therefore not recommended (I left it here for educational purposes): use `Apply` at the first level (`@@@`) this function `#2 - #1 &` (subtracting first and second elements of lists) and than map (`/@`) `Mean`:

```
Mean /@ Transpose[#2 - #1 & @@@ {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{9, 10}, {11, 12}}}]
```

> ```
> {2, 2}
> ```

Comment: Or, just for fun, `Mean[(#[[2]] - #[[1]]) &@(lst\[Transpose])]` (+1)